# Select a suggested Emmet in VS Code without expanding it

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, emmet

I cannot figure out the keyboard command to **select a suggested Emmet without expanding**, in VS Code...

- Type the letter `a`
- VS Code suggests an Emmet `a:link`
- now, I down-arrow to the Emmet with my keyboard
- I want to **select it**, but **not expand it**. Because I really want to create **5 links** in one go (`a:link*5`)

TAB key expands the Emmet. In this case - I don't want to expand it. I want to use the suggestion and type the quantity, as shown in the video link here:
https://youtu.be/aoQ6S1a32j8?t=1095

[image]

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question with recommendations.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I've been trying for the last hour to find some key command / option to be able to do it but I can't find anything. I've just tried asking Jessica on Twitter.

I've tried googling, exploring docs, looking at the keybindings and nada. But she clearly is able to do it.